# Java regular expression value.split("\\."), "the back slash dot" divides by character?

Tags: java, regex, backslash

From what I understand, the backslash dot (`\.`) means one character of any character?  So because backslash is an escape, it should be backslash backslash dot (`"\\."`)

What does this do to a string?  I just saw this in an existing code I am working on.  From what I understand, it will split the string into individual characters.  Why do this instead of `String.toCharArray()`.  So this splits the string to an array of string which contains only one char for each string in the array?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

My guess is that you are missing that backslash ('\') characters are escape characters in Java String literals.  So when you want to use a '\' escape in a regex written as a Java String you need to escape it; e.g.

```
Pattern.compile("\.");   // Java syntax error

// A regex that matches a (any) character
Pattern.compile(".");  

// A regex that matches a literal '.' character
Pattern.compile("\\.");  

// A regex that matches a literal '\' followed by one character
Pattern.compile("\\\\.");
```

The `String.split(String separatorRegex)` method splits a String into substrings separated by substrings matching the regex.  So `str.split("\\.")` will split `str` into substrings separated by a single literal '.' character.

Comment: :: It works alright.! But Could you ellaborate more on this, like why four backslashes ? Shouldn't there be three ?

Comment: A literal backslash has to be escaped once in a regex.  That gives 2.  Those 2 backslashes both need to be escaped in a String literal.  That makes 4.  Three backslashes will give you a Java compilation error.  Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: Why does Pattern.compile("\."); produce a syntax error?

Comment: Because `"\."` is a Java string literal, and `\.` is not a legal escape sequence in a Java string literal.

Answer (score 7):

The regex "." would match any character as you state. However an escaped dot "\." would match literal dot characters. Thus 192.168.1.1 split on "\." would result in {"192", "168", "1", "1"}.

Your wording isn't completely clear, but I think this is what you're asking.