# How to split the string a android

Tags: android

I am working on android application. I am getting the String value from webservice extension 
i want to split 4 from the string by using index .pls tell me how can do this

String version =  "1.4.2";

Comment: `String[] items = version.split("\.");`

Comment: can you see my answer below?

Comment: String version = "1.4.2";
String a_letter = Character.toString(version .charAt(2));

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
String version = "1.4.2";
Log.v("value ",""+version.split("\\.")[1]);
```

For more information Refer [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480284/java-regular-expression-value-split-the-back-slash-dot-divides-by-char),[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387622/split-string-on-as-delimiter)

Answer (score 1):

can you try this :

```
 String[] items = "1.4.2".split("\\.");
 String version = items[1].toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

have all the sub-part of your string using

```
String[] strs = version.split("\.");
```

now if you want 4 from (1.4.2), do following:

```
String mMiddle  = strs[1]; // it will give 4 as a string in mMiddle
```

if you want every sub-part:

```
String mStart = strs[0]; //returns 1
String mMiddle = strs[1]; //returns 4
String mLast = strs[2]; //returns 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
String version = "1.4.2";
String arr[]=version.split("\\.");
String value=arr[1].toString();
System.out.println(arr[0]);
System.out.println(arr[1]);
System.out.println(arr[2]);
```

thank you.