# Java Pattern / Matcher not finding word break

Tags: java, regex

I am having trouble with Java Pattern and Matcher. I've included a very simplified example of what I'm trying to do.

I had expected the pattern ".\b" to find the last character of the first word (or "4" in the example), but as I step through the code, m.find() always returns false. What am I missing here?

Why does the following Java code always print out "Not Found"?

```
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".\b");
                Matcher m = p.matcher("102939384 is a word");
                int ixEndWord = 0;
                if (m.find()) {
                    ixEndWord = m.end();
                    System.out.println("Found: " + ixEndWord);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not Found");
                }
```

Comment: You need to escape special characters in the regex: `".\\b"`

Comment: I've put it as an answer, with somewhat of an explaination. You can accept that as the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape special characters in the regex: `".\\b"`

Basically, in a String the backslash has to be escaped. So `"\\"` becomes the character `'\'`.

So the String `".\\b"` becomes the litteral String `".\b"`, which will be used by the Pattern.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upton AntonH's comment, whenever you want the "\" character to appear in a regex expression, you have to escape it so that it first appears in the string you are passing in.

As is, `".\b"` is the string of a dot `.` followed by the special backspace character represented by `\b`, compared to `".\\b"`, which is the regex `.\b`.

Comment: Hang on, is it a dot, or the regex dot representing any character?

Comment: just a dot will match any character, as expected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480284/java-regular-expression-value-split-the-back-slash-dot-divides-by-char