# Java regex only bashslash(\\) not working

Tags: java, regex

I am incorporating a pattern with has a backslash(\) with an escape sequence once.But that is not working at all.I am getting result as no match.

```
package com.test;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class TestClassRegex {
    private static final String VALIDATION = "^[0-9\\-]+$";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "1234\56";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(VALIDATION);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
        if (m.matches()) {
         System.out.println("match");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("no match !!");
        }

    }
}
```

How can I write a pattern which can recognize backslash literally.

I have actually seen another post :
[Java regular expression value.split("\\."), "the back slash dot" divides by character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480284/java-regular-expression-value-split-the-back-slash-dot-divides-by-char)
which doesn't answer my question completely.Hence needs some heads up here.

Comment: I think you need four total backslashes to get what you want. `"^[0-9\\\\-]+$"`

Comment: You probably need `String line = "1234\\56";`. But it would be helpful if you told us what your code does - does it compile? What does it print?

Comment: @Duncan, I really don't want to modify source of data.

Comment: @markspace, is there a simple and more accurate way to do it.

Comment: A string created using the string literal `"1234\56"` does not contain a backslash; `\5` is an octal escape sequence for `U+0005`, a control character.  I assume your real string is coming from somewhere else, and really has a backslash in it, but the literal your test code should contain two backslashes, as @Duncan said.  And the string literal representing the regex should have four backslashes, as @markspace said.

Comment: Ducan didn't intended to change your data, but in Java, this `"1234\56" means "123456" because you espace the character '5' which gives '5'. So to have a backslash in a variable, you need to double it, as he said. Oups, just saw the comment of Alan Moore, which already explains it.

Comment: Also, that other question you linked to doesn't relate to your problem.  Here;s a better one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242417/how-to-remove-the-backslash-in-string-using-regex-in-java/2242486#2242486

Comment: Doh!  It's actually `\56` (`U+002E`, or `.`), as Yassin points out below.  But the takeaway is the same: your regex isn't trying to match a backslash, and your test string doesn't contain any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"1234\56"` will not produce `"123456"` but instead `"1234."`

### Why?

The `\` in a String is used to refer to the octal value of a character in the ASCII table. Here, you're calling `\056` which is the character number `46` in the ASCII table and is represented by `.`

[image]

That's exactly the reason why you're not getting a match here.

---

### Solution

You should first of all change your regex to `^[0-9\\\\-]+$` because in Java you need to escape the `\` in a String. Even if your initial RegEx does not do it.

Your input needs to look like `1234\\56` for the same reason as above.